# Get previous page in UIWebView hierarchy

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, uiwebview

I need to be able to figure out what is the previous page in a UIWebView hierarchy so that I can disable the back button on certain instances. So, to clarify:

```
 User is on page A - clicks on link
 User is now on page B - clicks on link
 User is now on page C  - clicks on the **back** button
 User is now on page B
```

I need to be able to know that "previous" page *from* page B is page A. The method I'm using right now unfortunately only figures out the previous page the user was in in general. So in the situation above, it thinks the previous navigated page is page C.

Any help would be appreciated! :)

Comment: Show what you're "using right now", please.

Comment: I had this on webviewDidFinishLoad:
previousPage = [[webView.request URL] absoluteString];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time the user clicks on a link and a new page loads, your web view delegate gets a message. So "write down" that information each time! Now you know what "back" means.

Also, you can talk JavaScript to the UIWebView. JavaScript gives you a `history` object. A lot of the key functionality in UIWebView is through JavaScript! Apple hasn't bothered to duplicate it in Objective-C properties, because, well, why bother?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, Matt. I was kind of hoping UIWebView would provide an easier way than keeping track of things myself. But I gave that a try and it solved the issue. I'm also glad you mentioned the javascript solution, I'll keep that in mind for the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

years later....

In researching this same scenario, I came up with a nice solution.
Inside webViewDidFinishLoad, check for the property "canGoBack" and hide or unhide your back button accordingly. Thought this was too cool not to share. :)

```
if (self.webView.canGoBack)
{
    self.backButton.hidden = NO;
}
else
{
    self.backButton.hidden = YES;
}
```